# Azure Portal add a user who can create web apps, sql server and other resources

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

What is the correct way to add a user who can create web apps, sql servers, and other resources in an Azure Portal without making them subscription administrators?

Do you just invite them as a user in the AD section and give them roles? and which roles, it looks like Application Administrator and Cloud application administrator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the user has to be invited / part of the Azure AD that is linked to your subscription. Then, you can grant him access at a subscription or resource group level.

The right you are looking for is called **contributor**:

> Can create and manage all types of Azure resources but can’t grant
>   access to others.

Further reading:
[What is role-based access control (RBAC) for Azure resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/role-based-access-control/overview)